# Getting only the URL of the post thumbnail

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails

I wish to do something as simple as the_post_thumbnail('large') but I want the URL of the image only, not the HTML which goes with it. Is that possible ?

Comment: You've asked 8 questions, and accepted **zero answers**. You should start accepting some answers if you want people to keep answering your questions.

Comment: I didn't even know about the accepting system of this site, but now I'll accept answers I promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) to retrieve ID, then [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) to retrieve array, that will have URL as first element.